# Query going crazy with response time in small DB(mongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, performance, query-optimization

Explain output:

```
{
  "command": {
    "aggregate": "media",
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$match": {
          "status": {
            "$in": [
              "ordered",
              "assigned",
              "done"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "job",
          "localField": "_id",
          "foreignField": "media_id",
          "as": "jobs"
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "short_id": 1,
          "client_name": 1
          //<20 other fields, nothing crazy, just getting back simple fields>
        }
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "$and": [
            {
              "$or": [
                {
                  "type": "audio"
                },
                {
                  "type": "video"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "deadline": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "allowDiskUse": false,
    "cursor": {},
    "$db": "random",
    "lsid": {
      "id": {
        "$binary": "96mWaTC/RJOJrnjVYVn/EA==",
        "$type": "03"
      }
    },
    "$clusterTime": {
      "clusterTime": {
        "$timestamp": {
          "t": 1648551875,
          "i": 1
        }
      },
    }
  },
  "planSummary": [
    {
      "IXSCAN": {
        "status": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "deadline": -1
      }
    },
    {
      "IXSCAN": {
        "status": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "deadline": -1
      }
    }
  ],
  "cursorid": {
    "$numberLong": "8938039884351573029"
  },
  "keysExamined": 261,
  "docsExamined": 253,
  "hasSortStage": 1,
  "numYields": 12652,
  "nreturned": 101,
  "queryHash": "940ADCB9",
  "planCacheKey": "053108E6",
  "reslen": 155767,
  "locks": {
    "ReplicationStateTransition": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "w": 13161
      }
    },
    "Global": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 13161
      }
    },
    "Database": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 13161
      }
    },
    "Collection": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 13162
      }
    },
    "Mutex": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 509
      }
    }
  },
  "storage": {
    "data": {
      "bytesRead": 1338998,
      "timeReadingMicros": 664
    }
  },
  "protocol": "op_msg",
  "millis": 860,
  "v": "4.2.19"
}
```

The media collection contains 9100 documents. Each media can have a few jobs, but most of them has 0 or 1. 6.5k total documents in the job collection.

There is a compound index on the status, type and deadline fields - interestingly this makes the query even slower with 1-200ms. There is also a call on the total count, this has an issue on its own, because for some reason when the total documents of the filtered response is 220 or so then response time is like 800ms when the pagination is set to 20 items per page and 1200ms when the pagination is set to 100. And if I remove one of the filters - type filter for example, then the total count comes back as 4300 or so and then the query takes 23 **seconds** or so to complete, which is absolutely crazy for this collection size, personally I've never seen such bad computing performance through my whole career.

Interestingly when I exclude the total counting requirement - in the code level - the query time goes beyond expectation from around 800ms(regular bad query) to 1400-1600ms.
Question variations: Why? Why is it bad? How to do it properly? Why no proper description anywhere on mongoDB query optimization stuffs? Why the indexing makes the query even slower?

I tried to move around the $lookup section before the $match, after the $project, the above posted state turned out to be the fastest. Match could be combined, but shouldn't be the issue, we have queries with 10-20 filters, 1-2 lookups and trickier field settings in the $project section on the prod server that never shows up on the profiler as ones with performance issues.

Main question I'm mostly interested in: **How to change this to speed it up like it's a proper query?**

Comment: It is unclear why you add the second match after the lookup , if those conditions are added to the first match maybe better? also maybe a good idea to add example documents from both collections media & jobs  and created indexes to be easier to play araund for the auditory  , maybe also some info about the deployment RAM/CPU/wiredTigerCache ?

Comment: legacy code where the front-end can add 1 match with a different interface/structure and there are dedicated filters that can be used with sending top level parameters, and these 2 weren't merged yet cuz of the structural solution of the aggregation data provider uses them differently - it's planed, but didn't get there yet.

Comment: about the indexes; I read that first stage $match will use the indexes only, $sort can use indexes as well, but when I tested it with $match $sort stage didn't use the index, so I guess indexes can be used only once? Apart from that what I've seen is that if I add indexes the performance doesn't increase, but decrease - that is absolutely strange, but when I tested first I used compound indexes, and maybe that had a bad impact on the performance. Then I used 1 single field for index just to see the change, then the performance was about the same(matched the indexed field with the field in firs

Comment: t match).
And the DB is very very small comparing to the prod, so I wouldn't expect this. Also prod and dev DB is in mongoDB Atlas same cluster, which is an M20, which is stored on AWS EC2 instances with VPC peering setup.

Comment: M20 is 4gb ram - about 2gb free, 2 CPU vcores running mostly on 1-2%

Comment: It looks RAM is pretty low and you have many paralel operations ("numYields": 12652): The number of times the operation yielded to allow other operations to complete. Typically, operations yield when they need access to data that MongoDB has not yet fully read into memory. This allows other operations that have data in memory to complete while MongoDB reads in data for the yielding operation.